# cURL in php gets 404, browser gets OK

Tags: php, curl

I need help with my script (php)
I try to adress a service via curl at: 
http://xxxxxx.firewall-gateway.com:8090/avswcf.svc/GetProdInfoList

with the browser I can open it, but if I try it via cURL I get only 404 - not found

if I leave the port 8090, cURL works, but cannot find the service of course.

```
$url = 'http://xxxxxx.firewall-gateway.com:8090/avswcf.svc/GetProdInfoList';

$ch = curl_init($url);


//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
    'Items' => array(
        'PZN' => 1287400
    ),
    'Password' => 'xxxxx',
    'User' => 'avsweb'
);

$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0"); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Is there any Authorization for this URL ?

Comment: it could be a lot of things, maybe a cookie is needed in the request, or follow redirect is needed.. can you inspect the network call in the browser and post the request/response headers?

Comment: How do you send a POST with the browser? 404 could mean the requested resource in the POST data was not found. In other words the GET could work but the POST fails.